# Graphics pipeline for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, opengl

I'm interested in the graphics pipeline for Google Chrome. Specifically, can Google chrome harness OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Chrome can harness OpenGL for [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webgl)

> WebGL is based on **OpenGL ES 2.0** and provides an API for 3D graphics.[3] It uses the HTML5 canvas element and is accessed using Document Object Model interfaces. Automatic memory management is provided as part of the JavaScript language

```
chrome.exe --enable-webgl
```

See tests at [Khronos Demo Repository](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Demo_Repository)

This is not supported on all operating systems according to [Google Chrome Support](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=1220892)